# Can I have the id_token from google in my spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to catch the ID token when I use google oauth2 to secure my spring boot app?

When I use postman + keycloak to get access token I get back informations like:

```
{
  "access_token": "eyJhbGc...",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "refresh_expires_in": 8640,
  "refresh_token": "eyJhbG...",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "eyJhbG...",
  "not-before-policy": 0,
  "session_state": "779e9b7b-ae44-...",
  "scope": "openid email profile"
}
```

There is the id_token. Is it possible to get this id_token in my spring boot app after a user log in with google?

I want similar ID token that I can use but from google. I have a controller like this but did not find out if I can have this ID token and use its' claims.

```
@GetMapping("/userinfo")
public String userinfo() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println(authentication.getAuthorities().toString());

    return "Userinfo...";
}
```

Thanks in advance